# Bash script to read a particular after time stamp

Tags: bash

```
29/08/2023,11:26:42,Info,========== Cognos Configuration =========
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/sw/cognos/analytics/bin/slf4j-nop-1.7.23.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/sw/cognos/analytics/configuration/utilities/config-util.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
29/08/2023,11:26:48,Info, Silent exit with error code: 0
```

This is the log file. In this file, there are 2 timestamps I want to grep on "Cognos Configuration" This means logging has started. After the 2nd timestamp `(29/08/2023,11:26:48)` I want to grep "Info, Silent exit with error code: 0" This confirms my application has started/stopped correctly.

The timestamps are not consistent as they will change every time the application is started or stopped so I bash the script to check after the timestamp and see an error code if 0 says success other than 0 shows as failed.
Thir

with

```
sed -n "/$(date +'%d\/%b\/%Y')/,/*/p" cogconfig.log |grep -i "with error code:"
```

I am not able to see the error code

Comment: Did you try just typing the `date` command to see if it produces what you want? `%b` is a month name, not numeric. You want `%m`.

Comment: `grep "$(date +%d/%m/%Y).*with error code:" cogconfig.log`

Comment: `/*/` may not mean what you think. Is it a typo for `//` ?

Comment: If you would debug your statement (with `set -x`), you would see that your `date` command produces for today the string `29\/Aug\/2023`, which is different in syntax from what is in the logfile.

Comment: You have `date +'%d\/%b\/%Y'` which outputs `29\/Aug\/2023` — a string for the month name instead of the month number.  Change the `%b` to `%m` to get `29\/08\/2023`.  With `sed`, you can use a different character than `/` for the search marker by using a backslash before the marker — for example, `\@29/08/2023@` — which avoids having to generate backslashes in the date format.  I'm not sure what you expect the `/*/` term to match.  What it does match is a line containing an asterisk.  You should probably anchor the date to the start of the line with a caret `^`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming;

- The logging starts with the line containing `Cognos Configuration`.
- You want to find the line containing the second timestamp after the line
  above.
- The timestamp is not consistent. You cannot use the fixed string.
- You want to extract the string after the matched timestamp.

Then would you please try:

```
awk '
    f && sub("^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],", "") {
        print
    }
    /Cognos Configuration/ {
        f = 1
    }
' cogconfig.log
```

Output:

```
Info, Silent exit with error code: 0
```

- `/Cognos Configuration/ {f = 1}` sets the flag `f` so the preceding lines
  (including this line) are skipped with `f`.
- The regex `^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],` matches the timestamp followed by a comma.
  The `sub()` function removes the matched substring.

Here's a one-liner version just in case:

```
awk 'f&&sub("^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],", ""){print} /Cognos Configuration/{f=1}' cogconfig.log
```

With GNU awk which supports `{n}` quantifier:

```
awk 'f&&sub("^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4},[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},", ""){print} /Cognos Configuration/{f=1}' cogconfig.log
```

Comment: It might be worth using `{n}` in the ERE

Comment: @Fravadona thank you for the comment. I was just thinking to be POSIX awk compliant which does not support {m,n} quanifier. I'd admit the regex looks busy without using it.

Comment: `{n}` is POSIX though; but there's indeed a few older `awk`s that don't support it

Comment: @Fravadona I've updated my answer considering the majority of the cases.  Thanks.

Comment: That gets an A for effort and thoroughness. (no meat left on the bone for other answers)